# Como estruturar a partialView Pra fazer O modelBinder Corretamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Possuo um formulario que foi partido usando partial view, existe somente um Create para todos eles, ae ai acho que não tem nada errado, ao tentar submeter o formulario obtive o seguinte erro..... `

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_dbo.Laudoes_dbo.Empreendimentoes_EmpreendimentoId". The
>   conflict occurred in database "EngosEngenhariaContext-20180626101342",
>   table "dbo.Empreendimentoes", column 'EmpreendimentoId'. The statement
>   has been terminated.

Depois de procurar um pouquinho descobri que o objeto esta sendo passado vazio, chegamos aqui a questão principal, se eu tenho um numero **x de partias views**, e eu preciso que envie esses dados todos juntos, como faço? toda pagina desses partials tem que ter o .....

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Laudos"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

? o so a partial final que possui o botão create precissa ter isso?

segue um exemplo, basicamente todas partials seguem essa estrutura. Espero que tenha me feito entender, Desde ja grato

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Laudos"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <label>Interessado</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome_empreendimento" placeholder="Nome do empreendimento deverá aparecer aqui..." readonly>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header"></h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Observacao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Observacao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Observacao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.AcompanhouVistoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.AcompanhouVistoria, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.AcompanhouVistoria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.AcompanhanteId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.AcompanhanteId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.AcompanhanteId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Contato, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Contato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Contato, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tipo" class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.TipoDoAcompanhante, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.TipoDoAcompanhante, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "outros()" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.TipoDoAcompanhante, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Outro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", style = "Display: none", id = "label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Outro, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "Display: none" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.Outro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.DataVistoria, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.DataVistoria, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Finalizacao_Laudo.DataVistoria, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div>
        <a href="#tab_1_6" data-toggle="tab" class="btn btn-success">Seguinte</a>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>  

}


}
```

Comment: Acho que você precisa  ter  o  form apenas  na main view,  a partial view você não  precisa porem  toda via você precisa bindar o seus dados para a partial tipo  @Html.RenderPartial("NomeDaView", model)

Comment: Como o Marcos falou, você deve ter somente um form e todos os valores que você quer passar para a controller devem estar dentro do form, ou seja, suas partial views devem ficar dentro deste único form.